# Secure login from a div using Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

So in the past, I used ASP.NET pages to post a username and password from a login page. Since the code was located on the server and protected, the usernames and passwords were hidden from the user. Now, I have switched do a popup div on the page to login to the website. This div does not have an iframe in it, just pure html. I'd like it to authenticate without reloading the page. Obviously, the button inside the div will have to call a Javascript function. At this point, since I can't keep the username and passwords in Javascript because they are exposed, the only answer I have is to send the data to the server in the form of an AJAX request. Is AJAX the proper way to do this? What is to stop a hacker from posting thousands of AJAX requests and trying to hack the site?

Thank You.

Comment: Nothing stops a hacker from doing that. Use HTTPS as secure channel and do the authentication on the server side never the less. Everything only done on the client will be more insecure.

Comment: If I do HTTPS, can't they just open up the developer tools on their browser and start executing code? Thanks

Comment: Sure. Or they use curl, or the use another tool from the huge tool belt of an attacker. The problem is, everything you publish will be open to people you might not like to start playing around with your services. But to get customers you either put it on the internet or you only let them use your PC while you're watching.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do an AJAX request. You want to use [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) which makes it very easy.

For protection against a person doing thousands of attacks the best way is to only allow a given number of requests from the same IP address within a given amount of time - this is of course done server-side.

You could also make your script for checking credentials very slow so that it's not so easy to hammer your website with attempts. If you put a pause into your script of 3-5 seconds it will take a long time do many attempts. But of course, if someone makes many *simultaneous* attempts to your website it might not have the great effect without any other security measure at the same time.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if IIS has a maximum request limit by default?

Comment: I was thinking that I could do HTTPS to stop them from sending requests to the server, but can't they just open up the developer tools from their computer and start executing code via the browser through SSL? Thanks

Comment: Yes, but why bother using a browser when there are better tools for DOS-attacks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure IIS doesn't have request limit per IP address by default.
For Apache there might be a module that can be installed which will do the job. But that requires direct access to the server config and on hosted plans you don't have that. So you might as well just write the code for it yourself.
@schlingel is correct in that it's easy to use another tool to do https, POST or whatever mechanism is needed.
BTW, if you feel the answer solved your question thanks for marking it as accepted ;)